# Upload a file in Flask Peewee

Tags: python, html, flask

I want to upload a file in flask peewee. I have a code but it generate "IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/lookbook/uploads/1375134_766940759988081_2093520123_n.jpg'" error.
Form :-

```
 <form action="" method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>
      <p><input type=file name=file>
         <input type=submit value=Upload>
    </form>
```

View.py :-

```
from werkzeug import secure_filename
import os
UPLOAD_FOLDER = '/lookbook/uploads'
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER
@app.route('/up', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.files['file']
        filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
        #return filename
        file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
        return redirect(url_for('up',filename=filename))
        return 'hello'
    else:
        return  render_template('fileup.html');
```

Please guys help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the error message, it seems like the directory `/lookbook/uploads` does not exist.

```
>>> open('/tmp/no-such-directory/a-text-file.txt', 'w')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/no-such-directory/a-text-file.txt'
>>> os.mkdir('/tmp/no-such-directory')
>>> open('/tmp/no-such-directory/a-text-file.txt', 'w')
<open file '/tmp/no-such-directory/a-text-file.txt', mode 'w' at 0x1ec6270>
```

Make sure the directory `/tmp/no-such-directory` exists..